# Date off by 1 day IOS safari - AngularJS

Tags: ios, angularjs, datetime, timezone, mobile-safari

I have a reservation application with a c# mvc api mssqlserver backend and angular frontend, everything is fine in Chrome on browser

however when I go to Safari IOS the dates are off by a single day

```
for example - on browser: 28th reservation( fromdate:28th todate: 28th) 
startdate: 2018-06-28 00:00:00.0000000
end date: 2018-06-28 00:00:00.0000000
            - on IOS safari: 28th reservation(fromdate: 27th todate: 27th)


example: 2

on browser: june28th-july19th
on IOS safari: june 27th - july 18th
```

the dates are retrieved from the db table and I can ensure that their format is
(2018-06-28 00:00:00.0000000)

Additionally, I noticed that when I get that exact datetime on ios it's different than browser- for example, I checked into my reservation at 11:08am and on IOS it showed the same date/time as 7:08am this could possibly be a factor but I don't know how to approach this issue

Comment: Are you in the eastern timezone?  If so, it looks like it is basing it off of unix time (UTC) instead of using your timezone because there is no offset provided.  `momentjs` makes dealing with times and dates much easier, I strongly recommend it to others.

Comment: Yes i'm in the eastern timezone

Comment: @BShaps I'm using an offset "{{reservation[col.field] | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd' : '-0430'}}" still not working shows 7am at 11am

Comment: can someone help me out ? I'm really confused

Comment: Did you check out `momentjs` and consider switching to unix time?  It is hard to help you out further without your code though.  It is almost certainly a timezone issue.